# How to disable shared folders for puppet provisioner in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I want to disable creating and mounting any shared folders for vagrant VMs.

I've found a way to disable sharing main /vagrant folder and instead uploading necessary files, but not able to find a way to disable shared folder creation for puppet provisioner.

I want to upload puppet files to VM instead of sharing from my host OS. Is it possible to do?

Comment: I don't know if puppet provider plugin support an option for disable sharing of VM but you can try to use shell provisioning for manage start of puppet provisioning ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use rsync synced folder type ([the docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html)):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "puppet" do
    puppet.synced_folder_type = "rsync"
    # ...
  end
end
```